# Codeigniter duplicating image file name with my own upload library

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload, filenames, image-uploading

I'm using codeigniter and I have a html form where I have 3 images to upload. 
And I am trying to create a library to upload images, 'cause I don't want to repeat code.
The problem is, event though I change the "file_name" parameter, it is uploaded with the same name!

Here's my library:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UploadImage{

    private $fileName = NULL;

    public function __construct($params){
        $this->img = $params["imagem"];
        $this->nome_campo = $params["campo"];
    }

    public function upload(){
        if($this->img != ""){
            $img_name = $this->img["name"]; 
            $img_tmp_name = $this->img["tmp_name"];

            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img_tmp_name);

            $name = pathinfo($img_name);

            $ext = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $diretorio = './assets/frontend/img';

            if (!file_exists($diretorio)) {   
                mkdir($diretorio, 0777, true); 
            }

            $config['file_name'] = md5(microtime().$name["filename"]).".".$ext;

            $this->fileName = $config["file_name"];

            $config["upload_path"] = "./assets/frontend/img";
            $config["allowed_types"] = "jpg|jpeg|gif|png";
            $config["overwrite"] = FALSE;

            $ci = &get_instance();

            $ci->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$ci->upload->do_upload($this->nome_campo)) {
                $ci->data['error'] = $ci->upload->display_errors();
                print_r($ci->data['error']);
                return NULL;
            } else {
                if($width > 3000){
                    $config2["source_image"] = "./assets/frontend/img/".$config['file_name'];
                    $config2["create_thumb"] = FALSE;
                    $config2["width"] = 2500;

                    $ci->load->library("image_lib", $config2);

                    if($ci->image_lib->resize()){
                        return TRUE;
                    }else{
                        echo $ci->image_lib->display_errors();
                        return NULL;
                    }
                } else {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    public function getNome(){
        return $this->fileName;
    }
}
```

And here's my method in controller that uses the library:

```
function salvar(){

    $this->titulo = isset($_POST["titulo"]) ?  $_POST["titulo"] : NULL;

    /* UPLOAD IMAGEM */
    $img1 = isset($_FILES["img1"]) ? $_FILES["img1"] : ""; 
    $img2 = isset($_FILES["img2"]) ? $_FILES["img2"] : ""; 
    $img3 = isset($_FILES["img3"]) ? $_FILES["img3"] : ""; 

    $params1 = $arrayName = array('imagem' => $img1, "campo" => "img1");

    $this->load->library('UploadImage',$params1,"nome_imagem1");
    $this->nome_imagem1->upload();
    echo $this->nome_imagem1->getNome();

    $params2 = $arrayName = array('imagem' => $img2, "campo" => "img2");
    $nome_imagem2 = $this->load->library('UploadImage',$params2,"nome_imagem2");
    $this->nome_imagem2->upload();
    echo $this->nome_imagem2->getNome();

    $params3 = $arrayName = array('imagem' => $img3, "campo" => "img3");
    $nome_imagem3 = $this->load->library('UploadImage',$params3,"nome_imagem3");
    $this->nome_imagem3->upload();
    echo $this->nome_imagem3->getNome();

    $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
    $descricao = $_POST["descricao"];

    if($this->produtos_model->inserir($titulo,$descricao,$nome_imagem1,$nome_imagem2,$nome_imagem3)){
        echo "Cadastrado com Sucesso!";
    }else{
        echo "Erro ao Cadastrar!";
    }

}
```

It doesn't matter what I do, it always save the images with the same name, always adding a "1" to the end of the name. Example:

"0_88434600_1517851942.jpg" and 
"0_88434600_15178519421.jpg"

But, when a print the $config["file_name"] var, it DOES show me different names...

I have no ideia what's the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There error you are experiencing has something to do with the way CodeIgniter works: as it loads the first `$config` with `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` it doesn't change it every time you initialize your `UploadImage` class. Thus you need to load the upload library, than initialize the `$config` array, and [reset it](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#CI_Upload::initialize).

```
class UploadImage {

    private $fileName = NULL;
    public $error = NULL;

    public function __construct($params) {
        $this->img = $params["imagem"];
        $this->nome_campo = $params["campo"];
    }

    public function upload() {
        if ($this->img != "") {
            $img_name = $this->img["name"];
            $img_tmp_name = $this->img["tmp_name"];
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($img_tmp_name);
            $name = pathinfo($img_name);
            $ext = pathinfo($img_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $diretorio = './assets/frontend/img';
            if (!file_exists($diretorio)) {
                mkdir($diretorio, 0777, true);
            }
            $config['file_name'] = md5(microtime() . $name["filename"]) . "." . $ext;
            $this->fileName = $config["file_name"];
            $config["upload_path"] = "./assets/frontend/img";
            $config["allowed_types"] = "jpg|jpeg|gif|png";
            $config["overwrite"] = FALSE;
            // IMPORTANT
            $ci = &get_instance();
            $ci->load->library('upload');
            $ci->upload->initialize($config, true);
            // END IMPORTANT
            if (!$ci->upload->do_upload($this->nome_campo)) {
                $this->error = $ci->upload->display_errors();
                return FALSE;
            } else {
                if ($width > 3000) {
                    $config2["source_image"] = "./assets/frontend/img/" . $config['file_name'];
                    $config2["create_thumb"] = FALSE;
                    $config2["width"] = 2500;
                    $ci->load->library("image_lib", $config2);
                    if ($ci->image_lib->resize()) {
                        return TRUE;
                    } else {
                        $this->error = $ci->image_lib->display_errors();
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } else {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->error = 'No image found.';
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->fileName;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry. I commented the line where I set de $config[“file_name”] for a moment. I know it’s confusing, that’s because I changed it many times, trying to find a way of make it work. 

Comment: Well, that is the issue. The file won't be renamed without that variable of the array set...

Comment: I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to set the filename in your `$params` array (as I've shown in my example) or do you want the library to generate the filename as you are doing in the commented out line??

Comment: I guess it would be better the way it is commented. But even without that line being commented, it doesn’t work. There was a moment, that I echoed the file_name variable, and it showed me different names. But still the files were saved with the same name. That’s why I’m confusing. I’ll try again, and update here.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your original way. If you uncommented the line it should work as expected.

Comment: I can confirm that your original code w/ line uncommented is working on my system.

Comment: Actually, I can get the different names, when I alert those variables in the controller ($this->nome_imagem1->getNome()...), as you can see here = https://ibb.co/nENJJx

But, still, my photos are saved with the same name. It adds a "1" to the end of the string, perhaps because I set $config["overwrite"] = FALSE. 
Take a look = https://ibb.co/bQS7BH
But that's not what I need. I need the files being saved with those names I get in the variables (as in the alert)

Comment: I am able to replicate the issue on my system. I will look for the cause.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Check new answer.